# Changing the port of the System.Uri

Tags: c#, .net, uri

I have an `Uri` object which contains an address, something like `http://localhost:1000/blah/blah/blah`. I need to change the port number and leave all other parts of the address intact. Let's say I need it to be `http://localhost:1080/blah/blah/blah`.

The `Uri` objects are pretty much immutable, so I can access the port number through the `Port` property, but it's read-only. Is there any sane way to create an `Uri` object exactly like another but with different port? By "sane" I mean "without messing around with regular expressions and string manipulations" because while it's trivial for the example above, it still smells like a can of worms to me. If that's the only way, I really hope that it's already implemented by someone and there are some helpers out there maybe (I didn't find any though).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Have you considered the UriBuilder class?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx

The UriBuilder class provides a convenient way to modify the contents of a Uri instance without creating a new Uri instance for each modification.

The UriBuilder properties provide read/write access to the read-only Uri properties so that they can be modified.

Comment: One thing to note about the `UriBuilder` is that if you set the `Port` to **-1** it uses the default for the protocol, so useful if you don't want the port #'s output.

Comment: @PaulTyng thanks for that hidden gem! That's exactly what i was looking for. (along with the UriBuilder class)

Comment: What is Scheme, though?  What does it do, and what should I put there?

Comment: @cullub http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme -- often it will be http or https or ftp

Answer (score 55):

I second a vote for [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx). I actually have an extension method for changing the port of a URI:

```
public static class UriExtensions {
    public static Uri SetPort(this Uri uri, int newPort) {
        var builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
        builder.Port = newPort;
        return builder.Uri;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:1000/blah/blah/blah");
uri = uri.SetPort(1337); // http://localhost:1337/blah/blah/blah
```

Comment: Thanks, UriBuilder is great, and I like the extension method, so +1. Gonna mark jglouie's answer though seeing as he was first

Comment: In my opinion, using an extension here is not good. Providing a SetPort method, where you have to get the returned Uri is not expected for the user. For me it only makes sense to use it like this: uri.SetPort(1337);